# Laravel 4 Resource Controller NotFoundHttpException

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm using a resource controller to handle accounts in my website.
This is my route :

```
Route::group(['before' => 'auth'], function() {
    Route::resource('/account', 'AccountController');
});
```

And this is my controller :

```
class AccountController extends \BaseController {

    public function index() {
        return Redirect::action('AccountController@show', Sentry::getUser()->id);
    }

    public function show($id) {
        return $id;
    }

    public function edit($id) {

    }

    public function update($id) {

    }

    public function destroy($id) {

    }

}
```

I created the controller with the command line using : 'php artisan controller:make AccountController --except=store,create'

Although, for some reason, I get a NotFoundHttpException when navigating to the URL.

[image: NotFoundHttpException]

But I have no idea why. What could be causing this?

## EDIT:

## Filters :

```
Route::filter('auth', function()
{
    if ( ! Sentry::check() ) return Redirect::action('HomeController@getLogin');
});
```

Comment: what if you remove the leading slash in your route declaration, ie `Route::resource('account', 'AccountController');`?

Comment: It still throws the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it, I don't know what the problem was but I moved the route group to the first line in  my routes.php file and it works like a charm.

Comment: I also had the same problem and moving the route line up worked. Pretty weird. Did you know why?

Comment: No, I don't understand why it happens. Must be a problem with the framework itself.

Comment: Routes are executed sequentially in the Routes file. Higher routes take precedence over lower routes.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct. It works on my machine. It probably is fixable by `composer update`. It would show a 404 if the Controller isn't findable by the router.

If this doesn't work, double check the `auth` filter isn't doing anything weird.

Comment: That fixes the current error but now I get the error 'Controller method not found'

Comment: By the looks of it, the 'Controller method not found' is the new 'NotFoundHttpException' from what I've seen. So it's still throwing the same error. I've updated the OP with my filters.

Comment: Okay, and are you able to the `HomeController@getLogin`? It might be the case that this HomeController couldn't be found.

Comment: Yes, I am able to navigate to any action in HomeController.